# ASP:Button tag is onclick method is not calling

Tags: asp.net

Button on click method is not calling

Button code :

```
<asp:Button ID="personalSub" runat="server" ValidationGroup="personal" Text="Save" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="InsertPersonalDetail" />
```

C# Code :

```
protected void InsertPersonalDetail(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    Console.WriteLine("hello");
    MessageBox.Show("hello");
}
```

Comment: is calling it, but you can not see the `MessageBox.Show` because this message box is for desktop programming

Comment: Any other option which i can ensure that method is called or not  ?

Comment: just debug it - add a break point there - 
other way is to add a literal on the page, and there write something on that literal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have any problem on the page then you must see a compiler error.

You do NOT have compiler error witch is means that asp.net finds the `InsertPersonalDetail` function on code behind.

From what I see you call inside the button click two functions that are for desktop programming (not for web page).

Neither one can have any visible effect on your click - there is no console there to see anything, neither user interface to open the `MessageBox`.

```
protected void InsertPersonalDetail(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    Console.WriteLine("hello"); // have no effect on web page
    MessageBox.Show("hello");   // have no effect on web page
}
```

**So its called but you don't see it by just wait a pop up to appears**

To check this out, run it with debuger and add a break point there.
Or add a literal on page and add some text there to verify that is called.

eg, add on page

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="txtLiteral" />
```

and on code behind

```
protected void InsertPersonalDetail(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtLiteral.Text += "InsertPersonalDetail called <br />";
}
```